# Iterating through an array containing objects using a function and a parameter

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a function that iterates through an array containing separate objects with name, surname and age properties. The function should take a parameter "name" and return the name, surname and age in the console.

How would I do this? I've looked at some other questions but can't seem to figure out how to do it. I've created this so far...

```
var people = [
  { name: "Sue", surname: "Beckett", age: 50},
  { name: "Bill", surname: "Borough", age: 44},
  { name: "Janet", surname: "Jupp", age: 23},
  { name: "Peter", surname: "Pepper", age: 21},
  { name: "Samantha", surname: "Salad", age: 17}
];


function person(name) {
  // code here
}

person(sue)
```

Comment: Search for array `filter` or `find` in latest version of JS.

Comment: Make sure that you pass the name as string ("Sue" instead of sue), also check the case-sensitivity for the match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [**`Array#find()`** method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this:

```
function person(name) {
  return people.find(function(p) {
    return p.name == name;
  });
}
console.log(person("Samantha"));
```

**Demo:**

```js
var people = [{
    name: "Sue",
    surname: "Beckett",
    age: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Bill",
    surname: "Borough",
    age: 44
  },
  {
    name: "Janet",
    surname: "Jupp",
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Peter",
    surname: "Pepper",
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: "Samantha",
    surname: "Salad",
    age: 17
  }
];

function person(name) {
  return people.find(function(p) {
    return p.name == name;
  });
}
console.log(person("Samantha"));
console.log(Object.values(person("Samantha")));
```

**Note:**

- Make sure you pass the name as a `string` when you call your method, passing just `sue` without `""` will assume you have a variable called `sue`.
- Note that you can use `Object.values()` to show only the values of
  the object properties, instead of the whole object.

Simply write :

```
console.log(Object.values(person("Samantha")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var people = [
  { name: "Sue", surname: "Beckett", age: 50},
  { name: "Bill", surname: "Borough", age: 44},
  { name: "Janet", surname: "Jupp", age: 23},
  { name: "Peter", surname: "Pepper", age: 21},
  { name: "Samantha", surname: "Salad", age: 17}
];
    
    
function person(name) {
  for (var key in people) {
    var person = people[key];
    if (name === person.name) {
      console.log(person);
    }
  }
}

person("Sue"); // string always needs quotes: " or ' character
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter`:

```js
var people = [
    { name: "Sue", surname: "Beckett", age: 50},
    { name: "Bill", surname: "Borough", age: 44},
    { name: "Janet", surname: "Jupp", age: 23},
    { name: "Peter", surname: "Pepper", age: 21},
    { name: "Samantha", surname: "Salad", age: 17}
];


function person(personName) {
    var user = people.filter(function (user) {
       return (user.name.toLowerCase() == personName.toLowerCase());
    });
    return user[0] !== undefined ? user[0] : 'not found';
}


console.log(person('sue'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array by checking the lower case value of `name` property and `name` variable.

```js
function person(name) {
    people
        .filter(o => o.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase())
        .forEach(({ name, surname, age}) => {
            console.log('name:', name);
            console.log('suname:', surname);
            console.log('age:', age);
        });
}

var people = [{ name: "Sue", surname: "Beckett", age: 50 }, { name: "Bill", surname: "Borough", age: 44 }, { name: "Janet", surname: "Jupp", age: 23 }, { name: "Peter", surname: "Pepper", age: 21 }, { name: "Samantha", surname: "Salad", age: 17 }];

person('sue');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877514/is-it-better-to-compare-strings-using-tolowercase-or-touppercase-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

```js
var people = [
  { name: "Sue", surname: "Beckett", age: 50},
  { name: "Bill", surname: "Borough", age: 44},
  { name: "Janet", surname: "Jupp", age: 23},
  { name: "Peter", surname: "Pepper", age: 21},
  { name: "Samantha", surname: "Salad", age: 17}
];


function person(name) {
  people.map((data,index)=>{
    if(data.name == name)
    {
      console.log(data.name);
      console.log(data.surname);
      console.log(data.age);
      return;
    }
  })
}

person("Sue");
```

Comment: The provided example is far from being a good answer. Firstly one should not mix data processing with displaying data (here it is not even for debugging purpose that also would be questionable). Secondly one should not bend methods from its intended purpose, here *mapping* misused as *filter* that not even returns an expected result but does data-output instead.

Comment: i thought that he just want to log result in console

Comment: You are right, that's what the OP did ask for. I just criticize your approach which I do not consider feasible/valid for the already mentioned reasons.