# count of word occurrences in a list, case insensitive

Tags: javascript, dictionary, case-insensitive

What is the most professional way to obtain a **case insensitive** count of the distinct words contained in an array using plain javascript? I have done the first attempt myself but does not feel much professional.

I would like the result to be a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Imo, .forEach on the array, lowercase each word and count it in a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you  Rani Sharim. I was actually wondering about the possible use the reduce()

Comment: You already asked this question [Count occurrences of distinct words in array using a Map [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69543628/count-occurrences-of-distinct-words-in-array-using-a-map) If you didn't get the answers you were looking for you should edit the question not post yet another [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Comment: @pilchard the previous question was about enhancing my beginner coding attempt. And as suggested has been reposted in the suggested forum (code review). So a new question has been reformulated to suit this forum. Thank you for your kind concern and guidance.

Comment: Also all of these answers use `toLowerCase` but `localeCompare` with case insensitivity set is actually a better comparison, with `toUpperCase` coming in second and `toLowerCase` third. see [Upper vs Lower Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877514/is-it-better-to-compare-strings-using-tolowercase-or-touppercase-in-javascript](Is it better to compare strings using toLowerCase or toUpperCase in JavaScript?)

Comment: @pilchard Thank you.  You mean it's better to use toUpperCase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to store each word as a property and the occurrence of each as the value.

In the reducer function, check whether the letter (converted to lowercase) exists as a property. If not, set its value to `1`. Otherwise, increment the property value.

```js
const arr = ["a", "A", "b", "B"]

const result = arr.reduce((a,b) => {
  let c = b.toLowerCase();
  return a[c] = a[c] ? ++a[c] : 1, a;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

<sub>As a one liner: `const result = arr.reduce((a,b) => (c = b.toLowerCase(), a[c] = a[c] ? ++a[c] : 1, a), {})`</sub>

To convert it to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (sugged by [@Théophile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4885772/th%c3%a9ophile)):

```js
const arr = ["a", "A", "b", "B"]

const result = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  let c = b.toLowerCase();
  return a[c] = a[c] ? ++a[c] : 1, a;
}, {})

const m = new Map(Object.entries(result))
m.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key, ':', value))
```

Comment: thank you!  very nice. Can I get explicitly a map as an output (distinct values, count)?

Comment: Optimally, I would like to get as output a Map containing as keys the distinct words and as values the respective frequency (count)

Comment: @Pam If `result` is an object, try `const m = new Map(Object.entries(result))`

Comment: @Franjo Pintarić thank you for saying so. I am coming from other languages, and frankly, this use of "online functions" does feel a bit esoteric. I was wondering actually if it also feels professional to the people working in the field :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to store the results and then create a `Map` object by passing that object to `Object.entries`

```js
const arr = ["c", "A", "C", "B", "b"];

const counts = {};
for (const el of arr) {
  let c = el.toLowerCase();
  counts[c] = counts[c] ? ++counts[c] : 1;
}

console.log(counts);

const map = new Map(Object.entries(counts))
map.forEach((k,v) => console.log(k,v))
```

Comment: May quickly ask why ++ precedes counts[c] and not follows it ?

Comment: Sure. Please read this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript

Comment: ah yes, I was aware of the ++"pre" and "post"++ increment. I was wondering why here we need to have a "pre". Would we count 1 less ?

Comment: the result will be 1 for all keys because it will first evaluates the value and only then increment and store it

Comment: If we do it with ++counts[c] way it will increments the value, then evaluates and store it, this is what we would like (:

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted 'group-by' operation is fine, it doesn't address the complexity of case-insensitive/unicode comparison.

First of all, you can reduce directly into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), here counting characters as they are without accounting for case-insensitivity or unicode variations resulting in 20 'distinct' characters being counted from an array of length 24.

```js
const input = [ 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', '\u00F1', '\u006E\u0303', 'İ', 'i', 'Gesäß',
  'GESÄSS', '\u0399', '\u1FBE', '\u00E5', '\u212B', '\u00C5', '\u212B', '\u0399', '\u1FBE', '\u03B9', '\u1FBE', '\u03B2', '\u03D0', '\u03B5', '\u03F5', ];

const result = input.reduce((a, b) => a.set(b, (a.get(b) ?? 0) + 1), new Map());

console.log('distinct count: ', result.size); console.log('Map(',result.size,') {', [...result.entries()].map(([k, v]) => `${k} => ${v}`).join(', '), '}');
```

Based on the samples below, the method that results in the most compact count is using `word.normalize().toLocaleUpperCase()` and passing Turkey('tr') as a locale for this specific sample array. It results in 9 'distinct' characters being counted from an array of length 24, properly handling different encodings for `ñ`, equivalent spellings of `Gesäß`(`GESÄSS`), and accounting for locale specific case changes (`i` to `İ`)

```js
const input = [ 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', '\u00F1', '\u006E\u0303', 'İ', 'i', 'Gesäß',
  'GESÄSS', '\u0399', '\u1FBE', '\u00E5', '\u212B', '\u00C5', '\u212B', '\u0399', '\u1FBE', '\u03B9', '\u1FBE', '\u03B2', '\u03D0', '\u03B5', '\u03F5', ];

const result_normalize_locale = input.reduce((a, b) => {
  const w = b.normalize().toLocaleUpperCase('tr');

  return a.set(w, (a.get(w) ?? 0) + 1);
}, new Map());

console.log('distinct count: ', result_normalize_locale.size); console.log('Map(',result_normalize_locale.size,') {', [...result_normalize_locale.entries()].map(([k, v]) => `${k} => ${v}`).join(', '), '}');
```

Using this simple 'group-by' we can look at the variations between the available case comparison methods: [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), [`toLocaleLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase), [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase), and [`toLocaleUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase) and unicode variations can be accounted for using [`normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

**To lower case**

`toLowerCase()` – 15 'distinct' characters.

`toLocaleLowerCase()` – 14 'distinct' characters, in this case specifying Turkey('tr') as locale.

`normalize().toLocaleLowerCase()` – 12 'distinct' characters, again with 'tr' as locale.

```js
const input = [ 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', '\u00F1', '\u006E\u0303', 'İ', 'i', 'Gesäß',
  'GESÄSS', '\u0399', '\u1FBE', '\u00E5', '\u212B', '\u00C5', '\u212B', '\u0399', '\u1FBE', '\u03B9', '\u1FBE', '\u03B2', '\u03D0', '\u03B5', '\u03F5', ];
// ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'ñ', 'ñ', 'İ', 'i', 'Gesäß', 'GESÄSS', 'Ι', 'ι', 'å', 'Å', 'Å', 'Å', 'Ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'β', 'ϐ', 'ε', 'ϵ', ]
// input.length: 24

// grouping by toLowerCase()
const result = input.reduce((a, b) => {
  const w = b.toLowerCase();

  return a.set(w, (a.get(w) ?? 0) + 1);
}, new Map());

// grouping by toLocaleLowerCase('tr') [Turkey]
const result_locale = input.reduce((a, b) => {
  const w = b.toLocaleLowerCase('tr');

  return a.set(w, (a.get(w) ?? 0) + 1);
}, new Map());

// grouping by normalize().toLocaleLowerCase('tr') [Turkey]
const result_normalize_locale = input.reduce((a, b) => {
  const w = b.normalize().toLocaleLowerCase('tr');

  return a.set(w, (a.get(w) ?? 0) + 1);
}, new Map());

// log toLowerCase() result - 15 'distinct' characters
console.log('toLowerCase() '); console.log('distinct count: ', result.size); console.log('Map(',result.size,') {', [...result.entries()].map(([k, v]) => `${k} => ${v}`).join(', '), '}');

// log toLocaleLowerCase('tr') result - 14 'distinct' characters
console.log("\ntoLocaleLowerCase('tr')"); console.log('distinct count: ', result_locale.size); console.log('Map(',result_locale.size,') {', [...result_locale.entries()].map(([k, v]) => `${k} => ${v}`).join(', '), '}');

// log normalize().toLocaleLowerCase('tr') result - 12 'distinct' characters
console.log("\nnormalize().toLocaleLowerCase('tr')"); console.log('distinct count: ', result_normalize_locale.size); console.log('Map(',result_normalize_locale.size,') {', [...result_normalize_locale.entries()].map(([k, v]) => `${k} => ${v}`).join(', '), '}');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**To upper case**

`toUpperCase()` – 12 'distinct' characters.

`toLocaleUpperCase()` – 11 'distinct' characters, in this case specifying Turkey('tr') as locale.

`normalize().toLocaleUpperCase()` – 9 'distinct' characters, again with 'tr' as locale.

```js
const input = [ 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', '\u00F1', '\u006E\u0303', 'İ', 'i', 'Gesäß',
  'GESÄSS', '\u0399', '\u1FBE', '\u00E5', '\u212B', '\u00C5', '\u212B', '\u0399', '\u1FBE', '\u03B9', '\u1FBE', '\u03B2', '\u03D0', '\u03B5', '\u03F5', ];
// ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'ñ', 'ñ', 'İ', 'i', 'Gesäß', 'GESÄSS', 'Ι', 'ι', 'å', 'Å', 'Å', 'Å', 'Ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'β', 'ϐ', 'ε', 'ϵ', ]
// input.length: 24

// grouping by toUpperCase() 
const result = input.reduce((a, b) => {
  const w = b.toUpperCase();

  return a.set(w, (a.get(w) ?? 0) + 1);
}, new Map());

// grouping by toLocaleUpperCase('tr') [Turkey]
const result_locale = input.reduce((a, b) => {
  const w = b.toLocaleUpperCase('tr');

  return a.set(w, (a.get(w) ?? 0) + 1);
}, new Map());

// grouping by normalize().toLocaleUpperCase('tr') [Turkey]
const result_normalize_locale = input.reduce((a, b) => {
  const w = b.normalize().toLocaleUpperCase('tr');

  return a.set(w, (a.get(w) ?? 0) + 1);
}, new Map());

// log toUpperCase() result - 12 'distinct' characters
console.log('toUpperCase() '); console.log('distinct count: ', result.size); console.log('Map(',result.size,') {', [...result.entries()].map(([k, v]) => `${k} => ${v}`).join(', '), '}');

// log toLocaleUpperCase('tr') result - 11 'distinct' characters
console.log("\ntoLocaleUpperCase('tr')"); console.log('distinct count: ', result_locale.size); console.log('Map(',result_locale.size,') {', [...result_locale.entries()].map(([k, v]) => `${k} => ${v}`).join(', '), '}');

// log normalize().toLocaleUpperCase('tr') result - 9 'distinct' characters
console.log("\nnormalize().toLocaleUpperCase('tr')"); console.log('distinct count: ', result_normalize_locale.size); console.log('Map(',result_normalize_locale.size,') {', [...result_normalize_locale.entries()].map(([k, v]) => `${k} => ${v}`).join(', '), '}');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I just saw this. Let me try digest a bit this precious bulk of information, and I will get back to you. It's Very kind of you to provide all this insight :-)

Answer (score -1):

use set to get rid of duplicates and the spread operator to put it back in an array.

```
const  myarray = ['one', 'One', 'two', 'TWO', 'three'];
const noDupes = [... new Set( myarray.map(x => x.toLowerCase()))];
console.log(noDupes);
```

Comment: This produces an array of distinct entries, but not the count.

Comment: @BryanDellinger That would return the length of the array, not the occurrence of each unique item.

Comment: @Bryan Dellinger Thank you for answering anyway: at least I have learned a new constructor for Set :-)